# Fire xaml animation in style when bound property updated

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, eventtrigger

I have a wpf app with binding to properties in the code-behind.
They update thanks to the standard `OnPropertyChanged()` behaviour - so far so good.

I want to briefly flash the background of xaml object whenever that value is updated - to alert the eye to a change in value. I have a feeling that this should be easy, but I think there is a syntax issue.

So far, I have tried to flash the background of a `Label`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                                    To="Blue"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

..what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF animation on data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926451/wpf-animation-on-data-change) I guess, that you should specify the target name

Answer (score 0):

@Pavel pointed me in the right direction.

On my xaml controls, I needed to add `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` to the binding, like so:

`Content="{Binding ID, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"`

Comment: You would also have to target `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"` because a ColorAnimation can't directly set a Background Brush.